# When video works in IE9, it doesn't anywhere else

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I can't seem to get my video to play in all browsers.

The code below works everywhere, but in IE9 it displays a black box where the video should be, then below it it plays the IE video.

If I make the video tag conditional to all except IE, it doesn't work in Chrome or FF but IE is fine.

Help??

```
<video controls="controls" width="315" height="186" >
    <source src="/video/Ryan2.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="/video/Ryan2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="315" height="186">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=/video/Ryan2.mp4" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The longtail video player is being displayed in IE 9 because your conditional comment states "if less than **or equal to** IE 9". You should use `[if lt IE 9]` to target IE 8 and below. But with that said, a better solution would be to embed the longtail player in the video element itsef. It will be displayed automatically on legacy browsers that don't support the `<video>` element. Like this:

```
<video controls="controls" width="315" height="186" >
  <source src="/video/Ryan2.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
  <source src="/video/Ryan2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" width="315" height="186">
    <param name="movie" value="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="controlbar=over&amp;file=/video/Ryan2.mp4" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  </object>
</video>
```

I'm not sure why the mp4 won't play in IE 9. Does it play when you drag and drop the video file directly into the IE9 browser window? Are your server MIME types set up correctly?